# What is the difference between /check_token and user-info-uri endpoints in Spring OAuth2?

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, access-token

Spring exposes `/check_token` endpoint; see [this link](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

For `/check_token` we need to configure `RemoteTokenServices` and it extracts the token. However, we can also configure `UserInfoTokenServices` that essentially does the same thing.

The only difference I can tell is the first one is according to OAuth 2.0 extension: Token Introspection Endpoint, however, this endpoint doesn't return node 'active' according to OAuth 2 Extension which is mandatory. See [this link](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/)

But that aside, is there any other functional reason that we have these endpoints?

Comment: Hi! Did you get an answer for this question? I am also implementing token introspecting endpoint and would like to get all the information about this topic. Thanks!

Comment: @walts Hi. Not really as you see nobody answered my question. My guess is that you can configure spring's bean to automatically check this endpoint to verify the user... but I didn't have time to investigate more so I ended up designing Token Introspection Endpoint myself

Comment: Hi! I investigated a little bit about the active property and turns out that latest spring oauth release version returns it. Check this line here

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/a62250bdba177474e5e9520611c90523463629d2/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/CheckTokenEndpoint.java#L87

I ended up just overwriting this endpoint to modify response to my need but overall I think this could be used as token introspection endpoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I also had the same question but I made some research work and got my answer,I hope my answer can help you.If I made any mistake,please correct me.

There are two endpoints in spring security oauth2 and cloud-oauth2.

**check_token:**
defined in OAuth 2.0 extension Token Introspection. Its method is post,secured by HttpBasic authentication. It return the basic information.
It is a authorization server endpoint.

**user_info_uri:**
defined in openid-connect.
It returns the profile information(for example email address and birthday).It is mainly used in SSO login.It can be post or get method.
It is a resource server endpoint.
You can check the doc below to confirm.
[OpenIDConnect](https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api)

Let me quote some sentences to conclude here from below
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6342

The /introspect endpoint and /userinfo endpoint are very different and are used in different scenarios with the provider.

The /introspect endpoint accepts an opaque (typically) access token and returns a set of claims associated to the access token.

The /userinfo endpoint accepts an access token and returns a set of claims associated to the currently authenticated user.

Comment: Thanks! Although it's a bit late but I think this is the answer to the question.