# Are there any endpoint for check token in ADFS?

Tags: spring, adfs, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Oauth2 and ADFS for security purpose. However I can not find the endpoint for checking token from response of ADFS.

I also have Spring Authorization Provider which is written in Java. And my application called it by using these properties:

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=myclient
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= mysecret
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri= http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/authorize?resource=https://localhost:8443/login
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri= http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/token
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri= http://127.0.0.1:9999/login
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri= http://127.0.0.1:9999/oauth/check_token
security.oauth2.client.tokenName=code
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme=query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=authorization_code
```

And I have changed the values of the properties to connect with ADFS

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=myclient
security.oauth2.client.client-secret= myclient
security.oauth2.client.userAuthorizationUri= https://adfs.local/adfs/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://localhost:8443/login
security.oauth2.client.accessTokenUri= https://adfs.local/adfs/oauth2/token
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri= https://adfs.local/adfs/oauth2/userinfo
security.oauth2.resource.token-info-uri= https://adfs.local/adfs/oauth2/check_token
security.oauth2.client.tokenName=code
security.oauth2.client.authenticationScheme=query
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
security.oauth2.client.grant-type=authorization_code
```

However, I found that `https://adfs.local/adfs/oauth2/check_token` is invalid in ADFS.

How can I get the check_token in ADFS? check_token is Token Introspection Endpoint, however, this endpoint doesn't return node 'active' according to OAuth 2 Extension which is mandatory. See this [link](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/)
This is what Spring Authorization Provider do when return check_token endpoint

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/check_token", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, ?> checkToken(@RequestParam("token") String value) {

    OAuth2AccessToken token = resourceServerTokenServices.readAccessToken(value);
    if (token == null) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Token was not recognised");
    }

    if (token.isExpired()) {
        throw new InvalidTokenException("Token has expired");
    }

    OAuth2Authentication authentication = resourceServerTokenServices.loadAuthentication(token.getValue());

    Map<String, Object> response = (Map<String, Object>)accessTokenConverter.convertAccessToken(token, authentication);

    // gh-1070
    response.put("active", true);   // Always true if token exists and not expired

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

ADFS has no such endpoint and I don't believe it's part of the spec?

You could use:

https://[Your ADFS hostname]/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration

to get the keys to check the JWT yourself which is the usual practice.

There are many resources on how to check the JWT e.g. [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/validate-an-identity-token).

Comment: Im looking for Token Introspection Endpoint, however, this endpoint doesn't return node 'active' according to OAuth 2 Extension which is mandatory. You can get some information from the link in my post

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783648/what-is-the-difference-between-check-token-and-user-info-uri-endpoints-in-sprin You can visit here to understand what I mean about check_token